# Magento 1.9.3.8 Actual purpose of Cookie Restriction mode?

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

Hi guys I have enabled the cookie restriction mode in my magento installation, but cannot gather the purpose of this mode. it displays a banner for users to accept, but actually doesn't look to be restricting anything. So, is this just a loose cookie notice toggle setting and not actually considered in the functionality?

This is because for one I can see the cookies **frontend_cid** and **frontend**  both being set before the user even accepted the cookies storage. Defeating the purpose of it.

Hopefully, someone can clear this up for me.

Also, does not work in local install. I.e, in a xampp installation the accept button just redirects to:

http://127.0.0.1/mag19/cms/index/noCookies/

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/compliance-cookie-law.html : A google search might have saved the trouble of asking this question.

Comment: Prateek I have read that link and others. But, magento regardless stores cookies and also doesn't truly disable/restrict cookie usage. Only looks to be used for Google analytics. Please reevaluate the question.

Comment: http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm : See **EU legislation on cookies** part, it lists the cookies exempted from expressed consent.

Comment: So fronted is session id thus will be exempt?  Would you know from this list:http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/cookie-reference.html  which cookies won't be stored?

Comment: Not sure about M2, as haven't worked on it yet. But for M1, all the standard Magento cookies are exempt. It's GA cookies where this gets tricky, and hence, they won't be stored without consent if you are using cookie restriction mode.

Answer (score 1):

When cookie restriction mode is enabled, all users can still add products to cart, register or will be able to check out without problems.

This is because by EU law, these type of cookies do NOT require consent: https://wikis.ec.europa.eu/display/WEBGUIDE/04.+Cookies

However, all Google (Universal) Analytics Cookies will be banned until the user is accepting the banner and clicking on the button. You can try the `Google Tag Assistant` browser extension and just do the test for yourself. It won't show any recognizable Google cookies on your Magento pages until you gave your consent (If Google cookies are setup correctly in Magento).

So denying consent does not block or disallow all cookies by default, just the ones you don't really need in order for your shop to be ale to work properly (like tracking).